# mongo search for part of string match in words array

Tags: arrays, regex, string, mongodb, find

I want to find partial string matching in mongodb list element
for example my search string is:

*"Hello world we are on mars"*

my records tags are:

1. *words : ["hell", "bubu world"]*
2. *words : ["**we are**", "cookie"]*
3. *words : ["are nono mars", "w"]*

I want to get bask only record number 2 where **one** of the array elements is matched

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the exact answer you are looking for. However, I have outlined my thoughts in order for you to rethink about the requirement and possible solution.

You may need to rethink about how you wanted to design the solution. You may not be able to achieve what you expected in the single Mongo query because normally the database attributes would have more text and search string would have less words. As per your question, your requirement is opposite to it.

One possible solution for a typical text search in MongoDB is "Text" Index and use "$text" and "$search" in find.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text

**Create Text Index:-**

db.collectionname.createIndex({words : "text"})

```
db.words.find( { $text: { $search: "Hello world we are on mars", $caseSensitive: true  } } )
```

The result would be : 1 and 3

You can also perform phrase search by enclosing the pharse in escaped double quotes (\").